# Problems pattern matching using R regular expressions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to extract a string using str_extract. Here is a small example of the type of string:

```
library(stringr)
gs<-"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]}"

s='\\{\\\"type\\\"*\\}'

str_extract(gs,s)
```

I'd like to get a print-out of the entire string (the real string will have more characters of this type and should only return the piece I specified here). Instead I get NA. I'd be grateful for any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to do? Right now it seems you want to extract the string '\\{\\\"type\\\"*\\' from another string that does not contain that text. Therefore it returns NA.

Comment: Isn't it JSON? If yes, use a JSON parser to grab the values you need.

Comment: I'd like to extract everything from '"{\"type\"' to '}' - called s - from the string gs. I think the order is correct. It is geoJSON, within a JSON string. Unfortunately the parser converts the geoJSON into a format which makes it harder to get the data into wkt, which is the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
gs<-"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]} I DO NOT WANT THIS {\"type\":\"Not a Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]}"
s="\\{\"type\"(.*?)\\}"
result = str_match_all(gs,s)[[1]][,1]
```

To test, I added the string 'I DO NO WANT THIS', which should not be returned, and added a second object which type is 'not a polygon'

It returns:

> "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]}"
>   "{\"type\":\"Not a
>   Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]}"

So only the elements requested. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot :) I'm still not sure why my oriiginal method failed, but I'll try to figure that out. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user8119260  If this answer is helpful,  please upvote it.  If it actually answers the question,  please accept it as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I did upvote it but sadly it doesn't show as I'm newish to the site. I've accepted it as the answer.